# Windows 7 taskbar thumbnails stops appear

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, thumbnails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 taskbar thumbnails fail to appear](https://superuser.com/questions/116430/windows-7-taskbar-thumbnails-fail-to-appear)

Several hours after each boot the Windows 7 taskbar thumbnails stops appear.

See that picture in order to dustinguish IMAGE thumbnails from TASKBAR thumbnails. Here is the TASKBAR thumbnails:

[image]

And here is the IMAGE thumbnails sample: [Windows 7: Image thumbnails fail to appear](https://superuser.com/questions/71652/windows-7-image-thumbnails-fail-to-appear)

On my laptop it is easy to reproduce. Click the currently opened window (it should not be a group of windows) - it will collapse. Than hover the mouse over any other window icon, wait a second, and nothing happens. After that no thumbnail appear at all.

There is the way to return them back. You need to open two windows of the same application (group of windows), and click their group - two thumbnails should appear. After that thumbnails are back, until you click currently opened window...

It there a way to fix it?

[Previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/116430/windows-7-taskbar-thumbnails-fail-to-appear-closed) was closed by mistake and not reopened, so I created the new one.

Comment: Diago - you are very-very stupid person. You did same mistake TWICE. :) Please, READ the question before closing it.

Comment: @Vasily. How about you read the comments I made on your original question. However **insulting** someone is not going to get them to help you. I did not make the same mistake twice. I fixed a mistake where you did **not read the FAQ** for Super User. First learn how the site works before you starting shouting and being insulting. For future reference, these actions will get your account suspended.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry being insulting. Hope the first question will answered.